# angular template *ngIf compare against array

Tags: angular

I have a list of users displayed using *ngFor in component.html.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users; let i=index">
    <div *ngIf=" ... if user.id in whitelistIDs ... ">
        selected!
    </div>
    <div #else not selected..>
</div
```

The array in the component.ts.

```
whiteListIDs = [ "id1", "id2", ... ];
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes...

Check if the item is in the array like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users; let i=index">
    <div *ngIf="whitelistIDs.indexOf(user.id) > -1; else notSelected">
        selected!
    </div>
    <ng-template #notSelected>
        Your id is whitelisted!
   </ng-template>
</div
```

if the item is in the array, then it will have an index, which for arrays, starts at 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. So you therefore check if it's 0 or higher. If it is, you know that it is in the array. if it's less than 0, u know it's not in the array.

Comment: thanks! this works! May I know what if I am checking against a custom object's field? lets say I need to loop through an array of whitelistObjects and compare against whitelistObjects.id instead

Comment: @user776914 - Try: `*ngIf="whitelistObjects.some(x => x.id === user.id); else notSelected"`.

Comment: you can't use => in html

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta - Good point. He would have to wrap that condition inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the *ngIf using a function in component.ts

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users; let i=index">
    <div *ngIf="checkUser(user.id)">
        selected!
    </div>
    <div #else not selected..>
</div>
```

and in component.ts

```
checkUser(id:any){
   return this.whitelistIDs.indexOf(id:any) > -1;
}
```